# How to cast to a type abbreviation?

Tags: casting, f#

```
type floatType = float32
let a = 5.0
let b = float32 a // Works
let b' = floatType b // Does not work
```

Would it be possible to cast to a type abbreviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing `float32 a`, you are using the function `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.float32`, which does an explicit conversion to a single-precision float without units.

If you want to allow similar usage of `floatType`, you could add the following to your definitions:

```
let inline floatType a = float32 a
```

Now your code should work.

Comment: Actually in this case you are **masking** type abbreviation `floatType` with new definition of function type `floatType` that returns `float32`

Comment: @Petr It's no more masked than float32 is, is it? Type annotations will still work, since the compiler distinguishes uses as a type. Is there a situation in which `float32` would work, but `floatType` would not, after both definitions?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to use a type alias for casting, but you're not casting, that's not the syntax for casting. In your example you're using an [explicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx).

Casting is a different thing, it "converts" to a super-class (up-casting) or a sub-class (down-casting), see this modification of your example:

```
type floatType = float32
let a = box 5.0f 
let b  = a :?> float32
let b' = a :?> floatType
```

This example is down-casting and as you can see it works with the alias.

So it's not possible to cast from `float` to `float32`, even without type annotations.